# Using multiple ethernet switches to connect shorter ethernet cable runs with a mix of cat5e and cat6

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

Ive got multiple shorter runs of ethernet cables a mixture of cat5e and cat6.

I need to get a cable from the router to another area, there is no direct concealed cable but there are multiple shorter runs that im able to connect up. My plan is to use the existing short runs connected via ethernet switches, add all the devices onto the local network and give them all internet access.

(Ive attached a chart below to visualise the setup)

In principal would what Im proposing work ?

I haven't just tried this as Id still need to run some of the cables for this to work.

[image: network chart]

Answer (score 2):

It will work, but keep in mind that each equipment has a latency (the time a frame goes through the switch), so the transmission time from *router* to *final* device will be higher (we're talking about 10 - 30 microseconds per switch) if the connection goes through Ethernet switches than going directly through a single cable.

To achieve maximum efficiency each port on the switch that connects to non-shared media( **shared-media=hubs**) must be configured to full duplex, as well as the interface card of the equipment (router, printer, Finaldevice,etc).

Comment: Thanks @jcbermu - re. the latency if im connecting devices such as printers (requires access to local network) and smart tvs (requires access to internet for Netflix etc) would you think there might be a scenario where these where effected by latency, ie. they wouldn't preform their primary functions correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine, as long as you're not exceeding 100 m from any switch to switch or switch to device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your setup will work, Cat-5e and Cat-6 will work together just fine, and if possible [upgrade all the Cat-5e to Cat-6.](https://blog.tripplite.com/which-ethernet-cable-should-you-use-cat5e-cat6-or-cat6a/) But to maximize your speed and latency, you could remove one of the switches and connect the printer to the remaining switch.

the more [hops your traffic makes](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/latency) to you, the higher latency you will get.

Hope I was of help!